# Python ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'name', with unit test

Tags: python

I have production files which works fine with imports like these:

`Ant.py`:

```py
from TurnDegree import TurnDegree
```

But during the unit test (While running: `python -m unittest tests/AntTest.py`), there is an error:

```
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/langton-python/src/Ant.py", line 1, in <module>
    from TurnDegree import TurnDegree
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TurnDegree'
```

When I change it to below, the unit test is working, but now the production code fails:

```py
from .TurnDegree import TurnDegree
```

With error:

```
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/langton-python/src/Ant.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .TurnDegree import TurnDegree
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

For the complete source, see: https://github.com/douma/langtons-ant-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following which treats a more specific exception:

```py
try:
    from TurnDegree import TurnDegree
except (ModuleNotFoundError, ImportError):
    from .TurnDegree import TurnDegree
```

or

```py
try:
    from .TurnDegree import TurnDegree
except (ModuleNotFoundError, ImportError):
    from TurnDegree import TurnDegree
```

It is not a good practice to use `except Exception` because that covers all possible exceptions. This means that if your program raise an exception different from `ModuleNotFoundError` or `ImportError`, it will run silently.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a try catch to handle both cases like below.

```
try:
    from TurnDegree import TurnDegree
except Exception as e:
    from .TurnDegree import TurnDegree
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Try finding which directories to save your files at so you could import it easily,

```
import sys, pprint
pprint.pprint(sys.path)
```

You should get something like that:

```
['C:\\Python35\\Lib\\idlelib',
'C:\\Python35',
'C:\\Python35\\DLLs',
'C:\\Python35\\lib',
'C:\\Python35\\lib\\plat-win',
'C:\\Python35\\lib\\lib-tk',
'C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Each of these strings provides a place to
put modules if you want your interpreter to find them. Even though all these will work, the site-packages
directory is the best choice because it’s meant for this sort of thing. Look through your sys.path and find
your site-packages directory, and save the module, then try importing, do the same thing in what ever compiler you use.

Tell me if it helped you saveing it there.